# How to read the inherited model in ASP.net core api?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, postman

This is my model I add customerdetails model inside customergetdata

```
public class Customergetdata
{
    public CustomerDetails CustomerDetails { get; set; }
    public string order_amount { get; set; }
    public string order_currency { get; set; }
}
```

This is my CustomerDetails model.

```
public class CustomerDetails
{     
    public string customer_email { get; set; }
    public string customer_id { get; set; }
    public string customer_name { get; set; }
    public string customer_phone { get; set; }
    public string customer_bank_account_number { get; set; }
    public string customer_bank_ifsc { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to read the two model data. Like this:

```
var body = new Customergetdata
               {
                   CustomerDetails =
                       {
                            customer_bank_account_number = model.customer_bank_account_number,
                            customer_bank_ifsc = model.customer_bank_ifsc,
                            customer_email = model.customer_email,
                            customer_id = model.customer_id,
                            customer_name = model.customer_name,
                            customer_phone = model.customer_phone
                       },
                   order_amount = order_amount,
                   order_currency = order_currency
               };

request.AddJsonBody(body);
var response = client.Post(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
var msg = response.Content;
```

I got an error

> Object Reference not set to be an null.

Customergetdata returns null.

I want to pass the request body like this. Please share your knowledge. Thank you in advance.

[Need to pass request body like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWXYx.png)

[My Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUfuT.png)

Comment: Where I will added it in Code , Still It show's an Error

Comment: In your method add [FromBody] before the parameter Customergetdata

Answer (score 0):

To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter:
*public async Task Collectmoney([FromBody] Customergetdata model...)*